# Linux/weblogic Excel download giving corrupted characters

Tags: java, spring, jsp, response, httpurlconnection

I develop an Spring,Hibernate 5 project. I have to download Excel/pdf from another report app.

Locally in tomcat no any error or corruption. But when I deploy my project to Weblogic on Linux server, Pdf working properly but Excel data being corruption like in below image.[Corupted Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml56N.png)

The download takes place in jsp. And I tring to move it in servlet before.

Code part of download;

```
            response.reset();
            o = response.getOutputStream();

            String typeStr = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; 
            typeStr = typeStr + "; charset=UTF-8";
            response.setContentType(typeStr);
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + downloadName + "\"" + ".xls");
            url1 = new URL(reportUrl);
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();

            response.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            response.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
            response.setHeader("Content-Language", "en");
            response.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
            response.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            http.setRequestMethod("GET");
            http.setRequestProperty("Content-type", typeStr);
            http.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");

            http.setDoOutput(true);
            http.setDoInput(true);
            http.connect();

            i = http.getInputStream();

            byte b[] = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                int length = i.read(b, 0, b.length);
                if (length < 0)
                    break;
                o.write(b, 0, length);
            } // while()

            http.disconnect();
            o.flush();
            o.close();
            i.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            try {
                i.close();
                o.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is caused from html tags, I removed ***ALL*** html tags(html,body,head etc.) from jsp and problem was disappeared . . .